# Django loggin in AWS

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I was just wondering what is the current best way to perform logging within Django and AWS.

I was looking at this article, which suggested writing to the following location, but I have found that this doesn't work:

```
/opt/python/log
```

Then use commands such as

```
command: chmod g+s /opt/python/log

command: chown root:wsgi /opt/python/log
```

I have also seen articles that suggest using watchtower, but I don't like the idea of adding my secret access keys into the code:

https://medium.com/@zoejoyuliao/plug-your-django-application-logging-directly-into-aws-cloudwatch-d2ec67898c0b

What is the current and best way to do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can customise your logging in  `settings.py` file

Add this to your `loggers` section.

```
'loggers': {
    'django.request': {
        'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
        'level': 'ERROR',
        'propagate': True,
    },
    'APPNAME': {
        'handlers': ['applogfile',],
        'level': 'DEBUG',
    },
}
```

add this to `handlers` section you can specify filename path.

```
    'applogfile': {
    'level':'DEBUG',
    'class':'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
    'filename': os.path.join(DJANGO_ROOT, 'APPNAME.log'),
    'maxBytes': 1024*1024*15, # 15MB
    'backupCount': 10,
},
```

With this call you are using your customised logger.
`logger = logging.getLogger('APPNAME')`

Comment: I am getting errors in the test phase at the moment, I will include some of them below

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/logging/config.py", line 769, in add_handlers
    logger.addHandler(self.config['handlers'][h])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/logging/config.py", line 324, in __getitem__
    value = dict.__getitem__(self, key)
KeyError: 'mail_admins'

Comment: .........     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/logging/config.py", line 619, in configure
    raise ValueError('Unable to configure logger '
ValueError: Unable to configure logger 'django.request'